# set attrs programmatically on carousel

Tags: android

```
<package.controls.Carousel
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                android:id="@+id/base_carousel"  
                pj:UseReflection="true"
                pj:Items="@array/icons"
                pj:Names="@array/planet"
                pj:SelectedItem="0"
                android:animationDuration="200"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
```

I want to set Items and Names array programmatically.

Comment: What is this exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is but assuming you need an adapter for it!

Comment: please explain a bit more

Comment: I want replace this two on code pj:Items="@array/icons"
                pj:Names="@array/planet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity, get your component as this:

```
Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.base_carousel);
```

On your carousel object you should have setter methods to set Items and names

---

There's also a project on Github based on this carousel library:
https://github.com/ludovicroland/carousel-android

This library allow you to use adapter to manage programmatically Items and Names.

Comment: I have already done it. I want to set name and icon array to replace this pj:Items="@array/icons"
                pj:Names="@array/planet" but i cant find any set method.

Comment: Please share javadoc or website of your component

Comment: Downloading project required an account. Maybe you could add dynamically full Carousel component grammatically. What are constructor of Carousel available ?

Comment: I was downloaded the full project i can set any array on xml but i want to set it on my MainActivity class because the array came from database. public Carousel(Context context)  {
  this(context, null);
 }
 public Carousel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {}
 public Carousel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
  this(context, attrs, 0);
 }

Comment: Accept answer if it's useful for you